# Counting the number of subset solution in the subset sum (knapsack) with dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem, subset-sum

So I want to know how to count all the solutions for a knapsack problem. Namely I'm interested in finding the number of possible subsets from a set of numbers that have the maximum size of K.

e.g we have a set of items of size {3, 2, 5, 6, 7} and the max size is K = 13. So the solutions are {5, 6, 2} and {6, 7}. On the other hand there are two solutions; I want my dynamic programming algorithm to report there are two possible solutions.

Comment: What DP algorithm implementation is used? Just modify it a bit

Comment: Is it allowed to pick an item more than once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with dynamic programming. The basic strategy is to build a memorization table, `d[i][j]`, which stores the number of combinations using the first `j` numbers that sum to `i`. Note that `j = 0` represents an empty set of numbers. Here is a sample implementation:

```
int countCombinations(int[] numbers, int target) {
    // d[i][j] = n means there are n combinations of the first j numbers summing to i.
    int[][] d = new int[target + 1][numbers.length + 1];

    // There is always 1 combination summing to 0, namely the empty set.
    for (int j = 0; j <= numbers.length; ++j) {
        d[0][j] = 1;
    }

    // For each total i, calculate the effect of using or omitting each number j.
    for (int i = 1; i <= target; ++i) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= numbers.length; ++j) {
            // "First j numbers" is 1-indexed, our array is 0-indexed.
            int number = numbers[j - 1];

            // Initialize value to 0.
            d[i][j] = 0;

            // How many combinations were there before considering the jth number?
            d[i][j] += d[i][j - 1];

            // How many things summed to i - number?
            if (i - number >= 0) {
                d[i][j] += d[i - number][j - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the entry in the table storing all the number combos summing to target.
    return d[target][numbers.length - 1];
}
```

Just to add some Google keywords: this problem is also known as summing n coins without repeats to a target sum.

Comment: there is a typo in the last return statement. It should be `return d[target][numbers.length - 1];` not `return d[target][number.length - 1];`

Answer (score 0):

There is a dynamic knapsack solution for this task.In dp array dp[i] stores the number of subsets which their sum is "i". In this case your answer is dp[K].( Sorry for indentation problems I could not figure out how to make it right :( )

> `dp[0] = 1 ;
>   for( int i=0; i<N ; i++ )
>       for( int j=K-a[i] ; j>=0 ; j-- )
>           dp[j+a[i]] += dp[j]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Max's algorithm works for the case: [0,0,1] with target of 1. The answer is 4 but his algorithm will output 1. His algorithm only works for positive integers, because it assumes that a sum of 0 can only be achieved with empty set. However, it can also be achieved if 0 exists in the array. The more robust way of tackling this problem (and also more space efficient) is using a 1D dp array. The pseudo-code is the following:

```
int[] dp = new int[target+1];
for (int num : nums) {
    for (int s = target; s >= 0; s--) {
        if (s >= num) {  // can include num
            dp[s] += dp[s-num];  
        } else {  // cannot include num (can be omitted, here for better explanation)
            dp[s] += 0;
        }
    }
}

return dp[target+1];
```

The reason I backtrack from target to 0 in the inner for loop is to avoid duplication. Think about the example [2,2,2] with target sum of 4. If you iterate from index 0, then you would double count a 2 when you are at dp[4] (should be [1 0 1 0 0] instead of [1 0 1 0 1] after one iteration in inner loop).

Hope this helps.